# Shading the interior of a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Trying to plot the domain bounded by the triangle of vertices `A(1,1), B(2,2), C(1,3)`, by using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
    [xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=middle, xtick={6}, ytick={6}, no marks, axis equal, xmin=-1, xmax=4, ymin=-1, ymax=4, enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:3, variable=t]({1},{t});

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=A]({t},{t});

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=B]({t},{4-t});

    \addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:2}];

    \path node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
    \draw node[below left] at (1,0) {$1$};
    \draw node[below] at (2,0) {$2$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,1) {$1$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,2) {$2$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,3) {$3$};
    \draw node[below left] at (1,1) {$A$};
    \draw node[right] at (2,2) {$B$};
    \draw node[above] at (1,3) {$C$};

    \draw node[below right] at (1.5,2) {$D$};

    \draw node[right] at (1,-.8) {\footnotesize{$x=1$}};
    \draw[densely dotted,black]  (2,2) -- (3,3);
    \draw[densely dotted,black]  (2,2) -- (3,1);

    \draw node[right] at (3,3) {\footnotesize{$y=x$}};
    \draw node[right] at (3,1) {\footnotesize{$y=4-x$}};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I obtain the following output:
[image]

So none of the nodes is pointed out. Where do I wrong ?

Comment: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`, which you had in your previous question. With `compat=1.10` or lower versions, you need to use `axis cs:` in coordinates in `\draw` etc. if you want them to correspond to the axis coordinates, i.e. `\draw (axis cs:0,0)`. With `compat=1.11` and higher versions, `axis cs:` is default.

Comment: Why on earth are you using nodes to make the ticklabels though?

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. I removed by mistake \pgfplotsset command. I am using nodes to point out the coordinates, since they allow me to insert wherever I want and I don't know other method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike your previous question, you left out

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
```

With `compat=1.11` or newer, coordinates in TikZ commands (`\draw`, `\path`, `\node`) are interpreted as axis coordinates, but without a `compat` setting, or a setting of `1.10` or lower, you need to use `(axis cs:0,0)` instead of `(0,0)` if you want coordinates to get the same.

Most of your nodes are not needed in this case, let `pgfplots` make the labels for the x- and y-ticks. I would think that appending `node`s to `\addplot`s would be more convenient for the vertices of labels, and the function labels for the dotted lines.

A couple of other minor things: Why not use `\node` instead of `\draw node`? And `\footnotesize` is not a macro that takes an argument, it is a font switch that affects the following text in the same group/environment. So you use it as `\footnotesize text`, not `\footnotesize{text}`, to limit its effect, use `{\footnotesize text}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
  axis lines=middle,
  axis equal,
  xmin=-1, xmax=4,
  ymin=-1, ymax=4,
  enlargelimits={upper=0.1},
  % set the specific ticks you need
  xtick={2},
  ytick={1,2,3},
  no markers,
  % all straight lines, 2 samples is all you need
  samples=2,
  % sets the length of the ticks, i.e. the small lines
  tickwidth=0pt
]

    \addplot[thick, domain=1:3, variable=t] ({1},{t})
          node[below,pos=0] {$A$}
          node[above,pos=1] {$C$};

    \addplot[thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=A]({t},{t})
          node[right] {$B$};

    \addplot[thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=B]({t},{4-t});

    \addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:2}];

    \addplot[densely dotted, domain=2:3, variable=t]({t},{t})
          node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$y=x$};
    \addplot[densely dotted, domain=2:3, variable=t]({t},{4-t})
          node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$y=4-x$};

    \node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
    \node[below left] at (1,0) {$1$};
    \node[below left] at (1.5,2) {$D$};

    \draw [densely dotted] (0,2) -| (2,0);
    \draw [densely dotted] (0,3) -- (1,3);
    \draw [densely dotted] (0,1) -| (1,-0.5)
          node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$x=1  $};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgot to uncomment the x=1 node.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I am beginner with TikZ and I will take into account your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` and the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
    [xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis lines=middle, xtick={6}, ytick={6}, no marks, axis equal, xmin=-1, xmax=4, ymin=-1, ymax=4, enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:3, variable=t]({1},{t});

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=A]({t},{t});

    \addplot[no markers,samples=51, thick, domain=1:2, variable=t, name path=B]({t},{4-t});

    \addplot[gray!30,opacity=0.6] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:2}];

    \path node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
    \draw node[below left] at (1,0) {$1$};
    \draw node[below] at (2,0) {$2$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,1) {$1$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,2) {$2$};
    \draw node[left] at (0,3) {$3$};
    \draw node[below left] at (1,1) {$A$};
    \draw node[right] at (2,2) {$B$};
    \draw node[above] at (1,3) {$C$};

    \draw node[below right] at (1,2) {$D$};

    \draw node[right] at (1,-.8) {\footnotesize{$x=1$}};
    \draw[densely dotted,black]  (2,2) -- (3,3);
    \draw[densely dotted,black]  (2,2) -- (3,1);

    \draw[densely dotted,black]  (1,1) -- (1,-1);
     \draw[densely dotted,black]  (2,2) -- (2,0);
     \draw[densely dotted,black]  (0,3) -- (1,3);
     \draw[densely dotted,black]  (0,2) -- (2,2);
     \draw[densely dotted,black]  (0,1) -- (1,1);

    \draw node[right] at (3,3) {\footnotesize{$y=x$}};
    \draw node[right] at (3,1) {\footnotesize{$y=4-x$}};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've obtained the desired output:
[image]